# Mock exception in abstract class Java

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I need to test with `Junit` some exceptions in an abstract class.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractReport {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    private static final String PREFIX_NAME = "reportFile";

    protected Path generate(String templatePath, Map<String, Object> params, JRDataSource datasource) {
        // Temporal file to write the document
        Path file = null;
        try {
            file = Files.createTempFile(PREFIX_NAME, null);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception creating temp file",e);
            return null;
        }

        try (InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(templatePath); FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.toFile())) {
            final JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
            final JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            final JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, datasource);

            final JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(Arrays.asList(jp)));

            final SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (final JRException e) {
            logger.error("Exception processing report",e);
            file.toFile().delete();
            return null;
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Report template not found",e);
            file.toFile().delete();
            return null;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception reading report template",e);
            file.toFile().delete();
            return null;
        }

        return file;
    }
}
```

I need to test every catch from this code. Researching I found that with **Mockito** you can mock exceptions when invoking a method, so for example I could fire an exception when I invoke "generate", however, I don't know how to fire an exception inside my "generate" code (for example an `IOException` when creating the temp file).

Comment: If this class has no dependencies, there's going to be nothing to mock.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that in your case the exceptions are thrown by the static method calls. Mockito cannot mock static method call as it's considered bad design.
If you don't want to refactor your code you can use `PowerMockito`

```
@PrepareForTest({JRXmlLoader.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ReportTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(JRXmlLoader.class);
        when(JRXmlLoader.load(any(InputStream.class))).thenThrow(new IOException());
        //call the method of your test class
    }
}
```

This will make method `JRXmlLoader.load` to throw `IOException`. In the same way you can mock static methods to throw other exceptions.

You can refer to [this docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#mocking-static-method) for more details.

If you don't want to add extra dependencies, then I will suggest to encapsulate calls of your static methods:

```
class JaspreUtilsProvider {

    JasperDesign loadJasperDesign(InputStream reportStream) throws ... {
        JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
    }

    //encapsulating other static methods
}
```

and then pass this class as a dependency to your `AbstractReport` constructor. Now change all the call of static method to calls of this object

```
public abstract class AbstractReport {
    private final JaspreUtilsProvider jaspreUtilsProvider;

    public AbstractReport(JaspreUtilsProvider jaspreUtilsProvider) {
        this.jaspreUtilsProvider = jaspreUtilsProvider;
    }

    protected Path generate(String templatePath, Map<String, Object> params, JRDataSource datasource) {
        //.........
         final JasperDesign jd = jaspreUtilsProvider.loadJasperDesign(reportStream); // instead of JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
        //.........
    }
}
```

Now it' easy to create a subclasses of `JaspreUtilsProvider` that throws an exception and pass it your test class instead of real `JaspreUtilsProvider` instance. This is the cheapest solution.

Comment: Thanks Serghey. Right now I cannot add extra libraries to my project so I guess I will have to find another solution. Anyway just to understand it, in the part where you say "call the method of your test class", if I invoke to the method `generate` from MyReport, which extends AbstractReport, as soon as it reaches `JRXmlLoader.load` it will fire the exception? how does MyReport get `JRXmlLoader` (mocked) injected?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have call of `JRXmlLoader .load`, even if the call happens in you abstract class `PowerMock` is able to mock the call for you.

Comment: If adding extra dependencies is now your case, then you should incapsulate call of the static methods in another object that will preform this calls for you. And then pass this object to your class as a dependency.